# PolymerJS Iron-Ajax binding issue

Tags: javascript, polymer-1.0

I've built a data viz on d3 and using Polymer to wrap it as a web component. For some reason, I am unable to use data-binding and pass in my input. I'm not sure why the error is happening itself. I think I've handled cases where data is null or undefined but I still get it.

My index.html (this is the demo file that calls my polymer element topic-model:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="../bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    <script>

    </script>
    <link rel="import" href="topic_model.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
  </head>
  <body>
    <template is='dom-bind'>   
    <iron-ajax auto url="./topic_model_data.json" last-response="{{data}}"></iron-ajax>
    <topic-model mds="{{data.mds}}" topiccorr="{{data.topic_corr}}" topicsize="{{data.topic_size}}"> </topic-model>
    </template>

  </body>
</html>
```

My topic-model element:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="topic-model">
  <template>
    <style type="text/css"></style>

    <h2>Topic modeling</h2>
    <div id='topicModel'>
    </div> 
  </template>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="../d3/d3.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    Polymer({
      is: 'topic-model',
      properties: {
        mds: {
          type: Array,
          observer: 'drawxy'
        }, 
        topicsize: {
          type: Array,
          observer: 'drawradius'
        },
        topiccorr: {
          type: Array,
          observer: 'drawlines'
        }
      },
      ready: function() {
        var w = 640;
        var h = 480;
        d3.select("#topicModel").append('svg').attr('id', 'svg').attr("width", w).attr('height', h);
        console.log("topiccorr being passed is " + this.topiccorr);
        console.log("mds being passed is " + this.mds);
        console.log("topicsize being passed is " + this.topicsize);
        this.drawlines(this.topiccorr);
        this.drawxy(this.mds);
        this.drawradius(this.topicsize);
      }, 
      drawxy: function(val) {
        if (val !== undefined && val !== null) {
          var w = 640;
          var h = 480;
          var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
                         .domain([d3.min(val, function(d) { return d[0]; }), d3.max(val, function(d) { return d[0]; })])
                         .range([0.1*w, 0.9*w]);
          var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                         .domain([d3.min(val, function(d) { return d[1]; }), d3.max(val, function(d) { return d[1]; })])
                         .range([0.1*h, 0.9*h]);

          d3.select('svg')
            .selectAll('.circles')
            .data(val)
            .enter()
            .append('circle')
            .attr('class', 'circles')
            .attr("r", 40)
            .attr('cx', function(d) { 
              return xScale(d[0])
            })
            .attr('cy', function(d) { 
              return yScale(d[1])
            });
        }
      },
      drawradius: function(val) {
        if (val !== undefined && val !== null) {
          var colors = d3.scale.category10();
          var rScale = d3.scale.linear()
                         .domain([d3.min(val, function(d) { return d; }), d3.max(val, function(d) { return d; })])
                         .range([10, 40]);

          d3.select('svg')
            .selectAll('.circles')
            .data(val)
            .attr("r", function(d) { 
              return rScale(d); 
            })
            .style("fill", function(d, i) {
              return colors(i);
            });

          var w = 640;
          var h = 480;
          xyCoor = this.mds;
          var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
                         .domain([d3.min(xyCoor, function(d) { return d[0]; }), d3.max(xyCoor, function(d) { return d[0]; })])
                         .range([0.1*w, 0.9*w]);
          var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                         .domain([d3.min(xyCoor, function(d) { return d[1]; }), d3.max(xyCoor, function(d) { return d[1]; })])
                         .range([0.1*h, 0.9*h]);

          d3.select('svg')
            .selectAll('.text')
            .data(xyCoor)
            .enter()
            .append("text")
            .attr("class", "text")
            .text(function(d, i) {
              return i+1;
            })
            .attr("x", function(d) { 
              return xScale(d[0]); 
            })
            .attr("y", function(d) {
              return yScale(d[1]);
            })
            .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
            .attr("font-size", "11px")
            .attr("fill", function(d) {
              return rScale(d['r'])/2;
            })
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle");
        }
      },
      drawlines: function(val) {
        if (val !== undefined && val !== null) {
          var w = 640;
          var h = 480;
          xyCoor = this.mds;
          var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
                         .domain([d3.min(xyCoor, function(d) { return d[0]; }), d3.max(xyCoor, function(d) { return d[0]; })])
                         .range([0.1*w, 0.9*w]);
          var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                         .domain([d3.min(xyCoor, function(d) { return d[1]; }), d3.max(xyCoor, function(d) { return d[1]; })])
                         .range([0.1*h, 0.9*h]);

          var edges = [];
          for (i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < val.length; j++) {
              if (i != j && val[i][j] < 0) {
                // Note: '< 0' is because correlation is negative currently
                edges.push({
                  'source': i,
                  'target': j,
                  'correlation': -val[i][j] // negative to make it postive
                })
              }
            }
          } 

          var cScale = d3.scale.linear()
                         .domain([d3.min(edges, function(d) { return d['correlation']; }), d3.max(edges, function(d) { return d['correlation']; })])
                         .range([0.5, 5]);
          d3.select('svg')
            .selectAll('.lines')
            .data(edges)
            .enter()
            .append('line')
            .attr('class', 'lines')
            .attr('x1', function(d) { 
              return xScale(xyCoor[d.source][0]); 
            })
            .attr('y1', function(d) { 
              return yScale(xyCoor[d.source][1]); 
            })
            .attr('x2', function(d) { 
              return xScale(xyCoor[d.target][0]); 
            })
            .attr('y2', function(d) { 
              return yScale(xyCoor[d.target][1]); 
            })
            .style("stroke", "#ccc")
            .style("stroke-width", function(d) {
              return cScale(d['correlation']);
            }); 
        }           
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

I'm actually new to web dev so I'm hacking my way around quite a bit so there might be something basic/obvious that I might have missed :/

Comment: Also, if there is anything wrong or something i can improve on the post, please let me know. My previous account got some negative postings and I got suspended from posting more questions but for most of them I'm not too sure why I got downvoted :)

Comment: What response are you getting from your `ajax` in network?

Comment: Can you post some sample data.  Also you said you get an error...what is the error exactly?  Side note, d3.select in shadowdom might not work, its best to use document.querySelector and pass that to d3.select.